# Joining rows with columns in SAS

Tags: join, sas, transpose

I have 2 tables. 
1 table with all possible mistakes, looks like

```
mistake|description
m1     | a
m2     | b
m3     | c
```

second table is my data:

```
n | m1 | m2 | m3
1 | 1  | 0  | 1
2 | 0  | 1  | 1
3 | 1  | 1  | 0
```

where n is row_num, and for each m I put 1 with mistake, 0 - without.
In total I want to join them showing row_nums (or other info) for each mistake.
Something like:

```
mistake | n
m1      |1
m1  |3
m2  |2
m2  |3
m3  |1
m3  |2
```

Comment: Please show what you've attempted as per SO rules.

Comment: I i don't understand what you mean...
I attempted varios joins, but it seems to me huge and not optimized...

Comment: Post a sample of what you've tried. It's a rule on StackOverflow, questions should show what you've attempted to solve the problem yourself as it's not a code writing service. If you have an answer that inefficient that's fine but include it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are just asking to transpose the data.

```
data have;
  input n m1 m2 m3 ;
cards;
1 1 0 1
2 0 1 1
3 1 1 0
;
proc transpose data=have out=want ;
  by n ;
  var m1 m2 m3 ;
run;
```